# Taking index of a string

Tags: java, android

Hello I have an edittext and an button.

I want when the user enters a number by pressing the number to be taken and put a bet on the index penultimate number.
Basically, what should I do? Thank you.

I try to do this with the following code:

```
public class BarcodScanner extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
private Button scanBtn;
private Button nextLevel;
private EditText formatTxt, contentTxt;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scanner);

    scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    nextLevel =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_enter);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view1);
    formatTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
    contentTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
    nextLevel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String inn = formatTxt.getText().toString();
            int length_s = inn.length();
            char m = inn.charAt(length_s - 2);

            if ( m == 1){
               Toast.makeText(BarcodScanner.this, "قبض آب",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId()==R.id.scan_button){
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        if (scanContent != null) {
            formatTxt.setText(scanContent.substring(0, 13));
            contentTxt.setText(scanContent.substring(18));
        }
    }

    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
}
```